# jQuery does not find element with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a view with `ng-repeat`:

```
<div ng-controller="LogBtnCtrl">
  <li class="item log-btn" ng-repeat="logItem in logBtns">
    <div class="log-btn--graph">5,3,9,6,5,9,7</div>
  </li>
</div>
```

I want to call `jQuery('.log-btn--graph')` after the view is rendered.

```
angular.controller('LogBtnCtrl', function($scope, TodayLogBtns) {
  $scope.logBtns = [0,1,2,3,4];

  $scope.$watch('logBtns',
    function() {
      console.log('a', $('.log-btn--graph').length);
    });

  console.log('b', $('.log-btn--graph').length);
});
```

But it gives `b 0` and `a 0`.

After the view is rendered, I can manually get `$('.log-btn--graph').length` as 5 in console.

So I guess when I call at `b` and `a`, the view is not rendered yet. Then, where should I put the calling of `$('.log-btn--graph').length` to make sure it's 5?

Comment: That should be done in the DDO and you have an invalid markup......:(

Comment: dom code doesn't belong in controllers.....needs to be in directive. Controller runs before view is compiled. What is the jQuery for?

Comment: why don't you check for `$scope.logBtns.length`?

Comment: Second what @Jai says. You are using Angular so use Angular's methods

Comment: I checked. `$scope.logBtns.length` is 5. @Jai

Comment: The jQuery is to generate graph. Something similar to `$('.button').button()`.

Comment: Then no doubts you have to move your code inside directive definition object DDO because there you will get your dom node after view is compiled and there you can get two more callbacks `pre/post`.

Comment: How should this be written in directive? @charlietfl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have a `$watch` in your controller method. So, instead of looking for DOM nodes have a watch over the collection:

```
angular.controller('LogBtnCtrl', function($scope, TodayLogBtns) {
  $scope.logBtns = [0,1,2,3,4];

  $scope.$watch('logBtns',
    function() {
      console.log('a', $scope.logBtns.length);
    });

  console.log('b', $scope.logBtns.length);
});
```

---

I would mention that you have an invalid markup, `li` elements should be direct children of `ul`:

```
<div ng-controller="LogBtnCtrl">
  <ul>
      <li class="item log-btn" ng-repeat="logItem in logBtns">
        <div data-button class="log-btn--graph">5,3,9,6,5,9,7</div>
     </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Above you can see there are two changes: (1): added a `<ul>` and (2): added an attribute `data-button`. Now this can be done:

```
(function(){
   var app = angular.module('theApp',[]);
   app.controller('LogBtnCtrl', function($scope, TodayLogBtns) {
       $scope.logBtns = [0,1,2,3,4];

       $scope.$watch('logBtns', function() {
          console.log('a', $scope.logBtns.length);
       });

       console.log('b', $scope.logBtns.length);
   });

   app.directive('button', function(){
        return {
           restrict:'A',
           link:function(scope, elem, attrs){
               // here elem is div with attribute 'data-button' so:
               elem.button();
               // angular.element(elem).button(); // with jqLite
               // $(elem).button();
           }
        };
   });

})();
```

Comment: Then how to call jQuery with the DOM element? I need something similar to `$('.button').button()`.

Comment: `$('.log-btn--graph')` will affect each of that class in whole page each time one instance fires. First one in collection will get plugin applied to it many times .Better to just use `elem.button()`

Answer (score 0):

Using JQuery and AngularJS together produces some problems like non-updating data bindings (read doc on $digest, $apply and so on for further details).

A better aproach is to use the data model ($scope data) in your controllers directly (e.g.

```
console.log(logBtns.length)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a watch for any of this if all you are doing is modifying individual elements in the repeat.

You use a directive because it assures you that the element exits before the manipulation code is run. A directive also gives you direct access to the element itself ... which will be a jQuery object when jQuery is available in the page.

```
app.directive('jq-button', function(){
    return {           
       link:function(scope, elem, attrs){
           // elem is a jQuery object
           elem.button();
       }
    };
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="log-btn--graph" jq-button>5,3,9,6,5,9,7</div>
```